# Valor normal dentro de una función en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

```
// CONFIG ////////////////
var initialBetAmount = 100; // apuesta realizada
var betColor = 2;    // 1 o 2
var multiplicador = 10; // multiplicador de martingala dual
//////////////////////////

function bet()
{
    return //si lo elimino sigue dandome error undefined
    var bet = document.getElementById("bet-input");
    bet.value = initialBetAmount;
}
```

¿Qué puede fallar? Tanto si tengo el `return` como sino, me devuelve valor `undefined`.

Si esas lineas las pongo fuera del `function`, funcionan bien y me ponen el valor que yo quiera en el espacio.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Desde dónde llamas a la función?

Comment: desde ningun lado, me limito a pegar el codigo y ejecutarlo en la ventana del chrome.

Comment: En ese código estás definiendo la función pero nunca llamándola. Tendrías que hacer bet(); para llamarla

Comment: Vale, tenias razon ahora ya me pone el valor, pero me sigue saliendo undefined alguna idea de como lo elimino para que no salga undefined?

Comment: sigue igual, tanto con el return como sin, da undefined, eso si la funcion funciona correctamente, solo falla eso.

Comment: Si estás usando la consola de Google Chrome te da undefined porque no lo muestras por pantalla. Pon `console.log(bet());` y verás como ya no pone `undefined`.

Comment: Si copias el código de mi respuesta te saldrá bien, ya que tenemos el elemento html y todas las variables están definidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para completar lo que tienes, tu código debería quedar así:

Recuerda que debes tener un elemento html que tenga el id **`"bet-input"`**. Define la variable **`bet2`** fuera de la función, de la otra manera sólo puedes acceder al objeto dentro de la función.

```js
    // CONFIG ////////////////
        var initialBetAmount = 100; // apuesta realizada
        var betColor = 2;    // 1 o 2
        var multiplicador = 10; // multiplicador de martingala dual
        //////////////////////////
        var bet2 = document.getElementById("bet-input");
        function bet()
         {
           
           bet2.value = initialBetAmount;
           return bet2.value;
         }

         var valor = bet();// valor contendrá el resultado de la función bet.
console.log(valor);
```

```html
    <div id="bet-input"></div>
```

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[js](/questions/tagged/js)

Comment: Sigue dando valor undefined, no comprendo el motivo, he quitado el return y tambien ocurre lo mismo, mas ideas?

Comment: sigue dando undefined, no lo entiendo

Comment: mira, me da el valor que pones `100`

Comment: Si, ami tambien pero aparte me pone abajo el undefined, no se porque sale

Comment: Te sale por lanzar-lo directamente a la consola de chrome, haz un fichero, pon éste código y te irá bien.

Answer (score 0):

Hice la prueba de tu codigo y no sale `undefined`

```js
// CONFIG ////////////////
    var initialBetAmount = 100; // apuesta realizada
    var betColor = 2;    // 1 o 2
    var multiplicador = 10; // multiplicador de martingala dual
    //////////////////////////

    function bet()
     {
       var bet = document.getElementById("bet-input");
       bet.value = initialBetAmount;
       return bet.value;
     }

     var valor = bet();// valor contendrá el resultado de la función bet.
console.log("no sale undefined",valor);
```

```html
<div id="bet-input"></div>
```

Comment: Es que, tal y como le he puesto en los comentarios, creo que lo que no hace es mostrarlo por consola y por eso le sale `undefined`.

Comment: @Error404 pienso lo mismo o que se olvido de su div `<div id="bet-input"></div>`

Comment: Realmente yo he votado para que la cierren por `error tipográfico o que no se puede reproducir`.

Comment: @Error404 si tienes razon es ese error, sera mejor cerrarlo